# NameError when using "self" in class?

Tags: python, pygame

I have the following Python (3.2) code:

```
from pygame import *

class Application:

    def __init__(self):
        self.running = True
        self.display_surface = None
        self.size = self.width, self.height = 640, 480

        self.old_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks
        self.new_ticks = None

        pygame.init()
            self.display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

    def on_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.running = False

    def on_loop(self):
        pass

    def on_render(self):
        pass

    def on_cleanup(self):
        pygame.quit()

    def regulate_time(self):
        self.new_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks

        while (self.new_ticks < self.old_ticks + 1000):
            pass

        self.old_ticks = self.new_ticks

    def load_images(self):
        pass

    while(self.running == True):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            self.on_event(event)

        self.regulate_time
        self.on_loop()
        self.on_render()

    self.on_cleanup()

    test = Application
```

I'm having a problem with the following line:

```
while(self.running == True):
```

which throws me the error : `NameError: Name "self" is not defined.`

I am pretty much a python newbie and was hoping to use this time to get started on learning python and pygame which I could then use for my college project (two birds with one stone) and I cannot figure out why this error is being thrown at me.

Comment: A small nitpick - the [Python style guide, PEP 8,](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id39) says that `if( b == True):` is bad form. Instead, just use `if (b)`.

Comment: My first language is C++ so forgive me! I'll try to keep python style in mind for the future :P

Comment: If you're new to Python, you should read ["Idiomatic Python" by David Goodger.](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) It contains an amazing number of 'aha!' moments and neat tricks you'd never think of.

Comment: Just had a quick skim through and attempted the "import this". My mind was blown! I'll add this to bookmarks and read through it in the morning, it looks excellent, thank you for the link :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the `while(self.running == True)` is *not* in any method (`def`) so there is no such *variable* called `self` in scope (which is what the `NameError` says)...

...perhaps there is some missing indentation? Although the previous `pass` makes it look like more than this is missing: maybe `def run(self):`?

Remember, `self` is just the conventional (and proper) name given to the *first* parameter for a method by which the "current instance" is implicitly passed.

Happy coding.

Comment: I feel kind of silly missing that, for some reason I was under the impression the code at the end within the class executes when the module is imported (I have no idea why). I'm still getting used to this python sorcery! Thank you for the quick and clear response :)